# App Development with Ionic or Android

Tags: android, angularjs, performance, ionic-framework

i'm starting at this world of app development and after some researches i still don't know which one to use. 
For having a little knowledge in AngularJs,some recommended Ionic but, is the performance affected ?

Should i begin with Ionic Framework or Android native ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wether to go native or not is great battle among most app developers.
I would always opt for native, because it has every utility for the platform and supports the developer in every possible way. Hybrid aproaches are lacking nearly all of this, but are written in a cross platform language quite a lot developers are familiar with.

So on the bottom line it greatly depends on the needs of your project. But to get started, may try a little "hello world" with the android SDK and java. You will very quickly get to know a lot of the characteristics on android you will need to know even if you opt for hybrid. This knowledge will be essential, especially if you want to publish your app on Google Play or Amazon App Store.